# Extract sagittal and coronal cuts from axial view using pydicom

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

I am trying to read a series of .dcm files which are by default show axial view. Below is the code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pydicom as dicom
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

root_dir = 'mydcomDir'


def sortDcm():
        print('Given Path to the .dcm directory is: {}'.format(root_dir))
        slices = [dicom.read_file(root_dir + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(root_dir)]
        slices.sort(key = lambda x: float(x.ImagePositionPatient[2]))
        pos1 = slices[int(len(slices)/2)].ImagePositionPatient[2]
        pos2 = slices[(int(len(slices)/2)) + 1].ImagePositionPatient[2]
        diff = pos2 - pos1
#        if diff > 0:
#            slices = np.flipud(slices)
        try:
            slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].ImagePositionPatient[2] - slices[1].ImagePositionPatient[2])
        except:
            slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].SliceLocation - slices[1].SliceLocation)

        for s in slices:
            s.SliceThickness = slice_thickness
#        print("from sorted dicom",len(slices))         
        return slices 


dcms = sortDcm()
ref_dicom = dcms[0]

d_array = np.zeros((ref_dicom.Columns,ref_dicom.Rows, len(dcms)), dtype=ref_dicom.pixel_array.dtype)

for dcm in dcms:
    d_array[:, :, dcms.index(dcm)] = dcm.pixel_array

#    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
#    plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
#    plt.title("Coronal")
#    plt.imshow(np.flipud(d_array[idx , :, :].T))
#    plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
#    plt.title("Sagital")
#    plt.imshow(np.flipud(d_array[:, idy, :].T))
#    plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
    plt.title("axial")
    plt.imshow(d_array[:, :, dcms.index(dcm)])
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

As you can see from the code I could not figure out the relevant idx and idy for particular dcm file. 
So my question is how to get sagittal and coronal cuts and plot them, given the axial cuts?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
As @ColonelFazackerley answered perfectly. I am adding below line just to show how I used it.

```
# fill 3D array with the images from the files
for i, s in enumerate(slices):
    img2d = s.pixel_array
    img3d[:,:,i] = img2d
#then to view sagittal and coronal slices for each of the axial slice
for i, s in enumerate(slices):
    img2d = s.pixel_array
    img3d[:,:,i] = img2d
    corId = corId-1
    sagId = sagId-1
#    plot 3 orthogonal slices
    a1 = plt.subplot(1,3,1)
    plt.title('Axial')
    plt.imshow(img3d[:,:,i],'gray')
    a1.set_aspect(ax_aspect)

    a2 = plt.subplot(1,3,2)
    plt.title('Sagittal')
    plt.imshow(np.flipud(img3d[:,sagId,:].T),'gray')
    a2.set_aspect(sag_aspect)

    a3 = plt.subplot(1,3,3)
    plt.imshow(np.flipud(img3d[corId,:,:].T),'gray')
    a3.set_aspect(cor_aspect)
    plt.title('Coronal')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

Comment: For most types of DICOM image there is one axial slice in each file. if you want sagittal or coronal you have to load all the slices, make the 3D image and then reslice in the other plane.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have axial slice in each file.  But as you said I have to reslice in the other plane to get coronal or sagittal, how do i do that? that is my question. What is the process to reslice axial slice to get other plane view?? I could not find a single explained example for pydicom. If you can explain or provide example code of that reslicing , would be great.

Comment: stacking and reslicing is not pydicom specific. numpy would make it faster. i suggest looking up examples there.

Comment: Yes I know reslicing is not pydicom specific. But I was looking for example in python and unfortunately could not find a properly explained example. Can you provide one? 
Although I have seen examples from matlab but could not find good example in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"""usage: reslice.py <glob>
where <glob> refers to a set of DICOM image files.

Example: python reslice.py "*.dcm". The quotes are needed to protect the glob
from your system and leave it for the script."""

import pydicom
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import glob

# load the DICOM files
files=[]
print('glob: {}'.format(sys.argv[1]))
for fname in glob.glob(sys.argv[1], recursive=False):
    print("loading: {}".format(fname))
    files.append(pydicom.read_file(fname))

print("file count: {}".format(len(files)))

# skip files with no SliceLocation (eg scout views)
slices=[]
skipcount=0
for f in files:
    if hasattr(f, 'SliceLocation'):
        slices.append(f)
    else:
        skipcount = skipcount + 1

print("skipped, no SliceLocation: {}".format(skipcount))

# ensure they are in the correct order
slices = sorted(slices, key=lambda s: s.SliceLocation)

# pixel aspects, assuming all slices are the same
ps = slices[0].PixelSpacing
ss = slices[0].SliceThickness
ax_aspect = ps[1]/ps[0]
sag_aspect = ps[1]/ss
cor_aspect = ss/ps[0]

# create 3D array
img_shape = list(slices[0].pixel_array.shape)
img_shape.append(len(slices))
img3d=np.zeros(img_shape)

# fill 3D array with the images from the files
for i, s in enumerate(slices):
    img2d = s.pixel_array
    img3d[:,:,i] = img2d

# plot 3 orthogonal slices
a1 = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(img3d[:,:,img_shape[2]//2])
a1.set_aspect(ax_aspect)

a2 = plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(img3d[:,img_shape[1]//2,:])
a2.set_aspect(sag_aspect)

a3 = plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.imshow(img3d[img_shape[0]//2,:,:].T)
a3.set_aspect(cor_aspect)

plt.show()
```

tested against series 2 from this example 3D CT data
http://www.pcir.org/researchers/54879843_20060101.html

edit note: accepted as an example into the pydicom project
https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/blob/master/examples/image_processing/reslice.py

Comment: Could you explain how this simple floor division gives us each cut?

Suppose we have 200 slices, each one being an image 256*256. Reading the code, i'm getting this: for the axial cut, you get only one slice?

For the sagital plane, you get all slices, but only one portion of each one? The same for the coronal place?

Comment: I used floor division to give an integer to use an an index. I divided by 2 to give a slice from the middle (if you have an odd number of slices - if you have an even number of slices, there is no middle slice). A useful application of this is likely to use a different way of choosing a slice.